# Update pannel not working

Tags: asp.net

Dear all.
  I have an update panel and nested repeaters in it. I have image which when i click shows the other nested repeaters data and so on. The rows are shown and hidden using the client script written on code behind.

The Page is working fine , but it refreshes the page every time i click to show data. If i put page in update panel, the page stops showing rows.

How to register the javascript with update panel.

Best Regards
Imran

Comment: you need to show your source to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to register your javascript with the updatePanel: You place your javascript globally, out side UpdatePanel so your libraries loaded, and then using this code you initialized it on every update panel, if needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {

}
</script>
```

Comment: I have this SCript that i call from code behind. its working fine but when i put the my repeater in update pannel, the data is not displayed.
 function showrow(v, collapse, expand) {

            var arrayIDs = v.split('|');

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayIDs.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById(arrayIDs[i]).style.display = 'block';

            }
            collapse.style.display = 'block';
            expand.style.display = 'none';
        }

Comment: I want to mention that this page is extended from master page.

Comment: Solved Finally ..

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showrow",
                                                          "<script language='javascript'>showrow('" + AllShowCategoruies + "');</script>", false);